# How do I change the value of a label after inserting a data from the Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
 private void btnCheck_Click(object send, EventArgs ex)
 {      
        string querytxt = @"SELECT Count(itemno) FROM Items WHERE itemno = @itemno";
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC80978273\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Inventory;User ID=sa;Password=Rmdj1q2w3e!");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querytxt, cnn);

        cnn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", txtName.Text);

        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC80978273\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Inventory;User ID=sa;Password=Rmdj1q2w3e!");
            SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT itemno, categ, name, quant, price FROM Items ", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmnd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                label6.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                label1.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                label2.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                label3.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                label4.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
            }
            txtName.Clear();
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            btnCheck.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No data found!");

        cnn.Close();
  }
```

I have 2 rows of data in the database with "itemno" as my primary key. The textbox "txtName.Text" is the value of the item number(itemno) in the database. The value of the labels will depend on the input of txtName.Text. However, when i click the "Check" button, it only displays the first row. I have tried enterring the value of "itemno" on the textbox but the labels still display the values of the first row. How would I fix this to correct the display of the labels depending on the "itemno" that was entered on the textbox?

Comment: Instead of `if (dr.Read())` use `while (dr.Read())`. But then you will see only the last. The reason is, you have only one  control for multiple records. Use a `DataGridView` or store the current record-number and implement a next/previous record functionality.

Comment: your fetch command does not specify which Itemno hence it fetches all data back in fact, and also your code only assign the first row of data to your lables...

Comment: if your result > 0 than you are not using where clause in your query SELECT itemno, categ, name, quant, price FROM Items where itemno = yourtext box value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should amend your query use where clause to get the desired row on base of value entered in textbox like:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(txtName.Text);
string strQuery = "SELECT itemno, categ, name, quant, price FROM Items Where itemno = " + val;
SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
```